# Parsing html table using jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to parse HTML table using jsoup. I am new to jsoup and I have read some tutorial on it. I need to extract values from table for each column from this website: https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/pbp/201905160GSW.html. I tried getting every timestamps, but it's only printing a single element. This is the code I tried last.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/pbp/201905160GSW.html").get();         
Elements trs = doc.select("table");

for(Element tr : trs) {
    Elements tds = tr.getElementsByTag("td");
    Element td = tds.get(0);
    System.out.println(td.text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand your code?

It selects all tables and puts them into `trs` variable:

`Elements trs = doc.select("table");`

Then it iterates over each table:

`for(Element tr : trs) {`

From each table it selects all cells 'td':

`Elements tds = tr.getElementsByTag("td");`

then it takes only the first cell

`Element td = tds.get(0);`

and prints its contents

`System.out.println(td.text());`

Some of these actions are not necessary but now with that explanation you should have a good start.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I tried iterating each row by using doc.select("table tr"), it worked for some other tables I did, but doesn't work for this one. I'm not really good with html, so I don't know how to iterate each row.